# Plain text editor that supports shared file editing like in LibreOffice

Tags: latex, text-editor

I want to share a .tex file with another person for us to edit it together, I took a look over collaborative editing in Gedit, that is awesome.

Although it still lacks an important feature for me, that is: When one user edit something it stay marked with different color until the other accept the edition, and when one user delete something it isn't instantly deleted until the other user accept so.

Editing a file simultaneously doesn't matter for me, but recording one user's editing and only applying it after the other accepts do.

This feature is present in LibreOffice, I took a screenshot:

[image: LibreOffice Shared File Edition]

It is in Portuguese, but what matters is that black text is text that was already accepted from both users, blue marked text is text I wrote, but the other user still didn't accept and yellow marked is text that the other user wrote but I didn't accept yet. Then I can right click on the text and select to accept the suggestion and the marked text will turn black normal text. (Blue strikeout text is text I deleted and the other user didn't accept yet)

This is a key feature for me. I need to edit a .tex file this way, can be with Sublime, Gedit, Geany, Kile, etc. I prefer Gedit, Geany or Kile although any plain text editor that has this feature will be welcome. If this feature simply doesn't exist in plain text editors then I can edit the .tex files through LibreOffice, but I don't want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/). It's specifically designed for this task.

Comment: Well, Gobby is cool, although you cannot edit files alone, save it, and after the other person see it, both need to be connected in order to you perform an edition.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/). Kate is a powerful text editor that can open multiple files simultaneously.

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install kate
```

Or just click [**Kate** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kate/)

Comment: Kate doesn't have the feature which I am looking for.